# Creating a ball game for Android on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android game, what I'm trying to do is a kind of Ink ball game.

I explain, I have addedd a grid and 3 sprites mooving in this grid. What I want at the end is that when you click on a case in the grid, this case becomes dark and it means sprites will bounce on it and go in the opposite direction when they hit a border of one of this 'full' case. Then you click on all cases and at the end the sprites are all stuck in the same and last white case, you click on it and it erase the 3 sprites and you win the game's level.

For the moment my grid and sprites are here, but when i click on a case the sprites don't take care of it and continue in the same direction they are not bouncing... This is the first thing for which I ask for help because you'll in my code that I try two ways to add boucing but I miss something ...

And second request my sprites are boucing when they touch the top left and right border of the screen but for the bottom my grid finish before the screen's border so I want to add someting to make my sprites bounce on the grid's bottom border.

Please find here my GameView code first :

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

     private Bitmap robotSprite;

     private SurfaceHolder holder;
     private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;

     // Robot Sprite
     private int x = 30; 
     private int y = 30;
     private int xSpeed = 1;

     private int top = 10; 
     private int left = 10;
     private int right = 460; 
     private int bottom = 460;

     int[][] grid;


     Paint paint;

     Sprite sprite;


     private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();


     public GameView(Context context) 
     {
           super(context);

           gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);

           holder = getHolder();

           holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() 
           {

                  @Override
                  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
                  {
                         boolean retry = true;

                         gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

                         while (retry) 
                         {
                                try 
                                {
                                      gameLoopThread.join();
                                      retry = false;
                                } 
                                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                                {

                                }
                         }  //    while (retry)

                  } //   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 



                  @Override
                  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
                  {
                         gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                         gameLoopThread.start();

                  } //      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)

                  @Override
                  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
                  {

                  }
           });

           paint = new Paint();

           robotSprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

           grid = new int[10][10];


           for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
           {
             for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
             {
                 grid[a][b] = 0;
             }
           }

           robotSprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

           //sprite = new Sprite(this, robotSprite, 30, 30);


           sprites.add(  new Sprite(this, robotSprite, 30, 30) );
           sprites.add(  new Sprite(this, robotSprite, 130, 30) );
           sprites.add(  new Sprite(this, robotSprite, 230, 30) );



     }  //  public GameView(Context context)



     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
     {
         try
         {

           canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);       // White BackGround (I changed it)

           int x = 10;                          //Decale les cases sur le cote droit
           int y = 10;

           paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
           paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  // Draw Border - Do NOT Fill!

//sprite.onDraw(canvas);


           for (int rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++)
           {

               for (int line = 0; line < 9; line++)
               {

                   if (grid[line][rows] == 0)
                         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);    // Draw Border - Do NOT Fill!
                   else
                         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);   // Draw Border and FILL

                   canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+50, y+50, paint );

                   x = x + 50;

               }   // for (int line = 0; line < 9; line++)

               x = 10;
               y = y + 50;

           } //  for (int rows =0; rows < 9; rows++)

           for (Sprite sprite : sprites) 
           {
               sprite.Draw(canvas);

           }


         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
                Log.w("GameView","Exception = " + e.toString() );
         }

     }  //    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 


     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
     {
         int x = (int)event.getX()/50;
         int y = (int)event.getY()/50;

         try
         {
             if (grid[x][y] == 1)
                 grid[x][y] = 0;
             else
                 grid[x][y] = 1;
         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
                Log.w("GameView","TOUCH Exception = " + e.toString() );
         }


         Log.w("TOUCH","X = " + (int)event.getY()/50 + " Y = " + (int)event.getX()/50);


         for (int i = sprites.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
             Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
             if (sprite.isCollition(event.getX(),event.getY())) {
                 sprites.remove(sprite);
             }
         }

         for (int i = sprites.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
             Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
             if (sprite.isOutofBounds(event.getX(),event.getY()) == true) {

                 // change direction 
                 sprite.ChangeDirection();

             }
         }
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);

     }
```

And here my Sprite.java code where I tried two methods (isOutofBounds and ChangeDirection, see update and update 2) :

```
    public Sprite(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp, int newX, int newY) 
    {

          this.gameView = gameView;
          this.bmp = bmp;

          this.x = newX;
          this.y = newY;

          this.width = bmp.getWidth();
          this.height = bmp.getHeight();

    }   //   public Sprite(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp) 

private void update() 
    {
         if (x > gameView.getWidth() - width - xSpeed || x + xSpeed < 0) 
         {
             xSpeed = -xSpeed;
         }

         x = x + xSpeed;

         if (y > gameView.getHeight() - height - ySpeed || y + ySpeed < 0) 
         {
             ySpeed = -ySpeed;
         }

         y = y + ySpeed;



    }   //  private void update()

private void update2()
{
    if (isOutofBounds(x, y) == true) 
     {
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;
     }


}

    public void ChangeDirection()
    {
        update2();
    }



    public void Draw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        update();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);

    }



    public boolean isCollition(float x2, float y2) {
        return x2 > x && x2 < x + width && y2 > y && y2 < y + height;
    }

    public boolean isOutofBounds(float x2, float y2){

        // Y
         int top = 10; 
         int bottom = 460;
        // X         
         int left = 10;
         int right = 460; 

        if (y2 < top | y2 > bottom)
            // outside bounds
            return true;


        if(x2 < left | x2 > right)
            // outside bounds
            return true;

         return false;



    }




}   //  public class Sprite {
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: you only test the collision when you actually touch the tile. You need to also test it when you move the sprites.

Comment: You mean ?
My sprites are mooving randomly on the screen I just want that when I click on a case of my grid this case becomes 'full' and sprites will bounce on it and go in the opposite direction. For the moment it just changes the color of my case and sprites aren't bouncing on it

Any idea of how I can change it ?

Comment: the collision does not occur when you touch the grid, but when the sprite move into the tile. Also, your `ChangeDirection` method does not do anything unless the sprite is out of the screen.

Comment: Ok so I can erase my ChangeDirection method and how should I define a method to make the collision only when a sprite move into a 'full' case (you call it a 'tile' right?)

Comment: Oh okay I understand now what I want is to change my IsCollition method because for the moment the collition event doesn't occur when the sprite move into the tile but what I should do ? Add sprite.IsCollition(); to my GameView.java ?